# Python GTK - switch between widgets - embed a tree in widget or window

Tags: java, python, swing, gtk, pygtk

i have a window with a menu bar and 3 menu items. The first two items should allow the user to switch between the main "window" (for java I would say panel) and the log "window". I was used to use a card layout in swing - java.
But i want to do the same in python gtk.

The second question is - how do i display a tree and be side the tree, let say 4 buttons.
The code for the tree is - http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-CellRenderers.html#cellrendererfig

I hope you can give me some hints how to handle the mentioned issues :/

My window looks like this at the moment:
[image]

My code is at the moment this:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require("2.0")
import gtk, gobject

class PyApp(gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(PyApp, self).__init__()

        self.set_title("Utilities Testing Tool")
        self.set_size_request(700, 500)
        self.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.Color(6400, 6400, 6440))
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)

        mb = gtk.MenuBar()


        treem = gtk.MenuItem("Tree Window")
        treem.connect("button_press_event", self.open_tree_widget)
        logm = gtk.MenuItem("Log Window")
        logm.connect("button_press_event", self.open_log_widget)
        exit = gtk.MenuItem("Exit")
        exit.connect("button_press_event", gtk.main_quit)
        mb.append(treem)
        mb.append(logm)
        mb.append(exit)


        self.vbox = gtk.VBox(False, 2)
        self.vbox.pack_start(mb, False, False, 0)

        self.add(self.vbox)

        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()

    def open_tree_widget(self, arg0, arg1):
        print("tree")


    def open_log_widget(self,  arg0, arg1):
        print("log")

    def replace_widget(self, current, new):
        """
        Replace one widget with another.
        'current' has to be inside a container (e.g. gtk.VBox).
        """
        container = current.parent
        assert container # is "current" inside a container widget?

        # stolen from gazpacho code (widgets/base/base.py):
        props = {}
        for pspec in gtk.container_class_list_child_properties(container):
            props[pspec.name] = container.child_get_property(current, pspec.name)

        gtk.Container.remove(container, current)
        container.add(new)

        for name, value in props.items():
            container.child_set_property(new, name, value)    

PyApp()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: Does the card layout in Swing allow you to switch between two widgets? If so, you can either switch to GTK+ 3 which has GtkStack that is the same thing, or manually show and hide the widgets that you want.

Comment: The GtkStack can also be used in combination with a GtkStackSwitcher if you don't want to implement the necessary buttons on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read in the meantime some parts of public pygtk tutorial and I have written following solution.

The solution contains two classes inherrited by the class gtk.table.

The method "replace_widget" gets called if one of the buttons get pushed to switch the window. "replace_widget" gets two arguments, the current widget and the wished widget. See the following code. I hope that this answer may help some people who have the same problem. Thanks for your answers.

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require("2.0")
import gtk, gobject
class clTableTree(gtk.Table):
    def __init__(self):
        super(clTableTree, self).__init__(15,15,True)

        self.set_row_spacings(5)
        self.btnStartTest = gtk.Button("Start testing Process")
        self.attach(self.btnStartTest,6,9,13,14)

        self.btnActivate = gtk.Button("Activate")
        self.attach(self.btnActivate,12,14,3,4)

        self.btnDeactivate = gtk.Button("Deactivate")
        self.attach(self.btnDeactivate,12,14,4,5)

        self.btnDuplicateNode = gtk.Button("Duplicate Node")
        self.attach(self.btnDuplicateNode,12,14,5,6)        

        self.btnDeleteNode = gtk.Button("Delete Node")
        self.attach(self.btnDeleteNode,12,14,6,7) 


class clTableLog(gtk.Table):
    def __init__(self):
        super(clTableLog, self).__init__(15,15,True)

        self.set_row_spacings(5)
        self.btnSaveLogAs = gtk.Button("Save log as...")
        self.attach(self.btnSaveLogAs,6,9,13,14)
        self.btnSaveLogAs.show()

        self.btnRefresh = gtk.Button("Refresh")
        self.attach(self.btnRefresh,12,14,5,6)        
        self.btnRefresh.show()

        self.btnClearALL = gtk.Button("Clear all")
        self.attach(self.btnClearALL,12,14,6,7)  
        self.btnClearALL.show()

class PyApp(gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(PyApp, self).__init__()

        self.set_title("Utilities Testing Tool")
        self.set_size_request(700, 500)
        #self.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.Color(6400, 6400, 6440))
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)

        mb = gtk.MenuBar()


        treem = gtk.MenuItem("Tree Window")
        treem.connect("button_press_event", self.open_tree_widget)
        logm = gtk.MenuItem("Log Window")
        logm.connect("button_press_event", self.open_log_widget)
        exit = gtk.MenuItem("Exit")
        exit.connect("button_press_event", gtk.main_quit)
        mb.append(treem)
        mb.append(logm)
        mb.append(exit)


        self.vbox = gtk.VBox(False, 2)
        self.vbox.pack_start(mb, False, False, 0)

        self.tableTreeWindow = self.create_table_tree()
        self.tableLogWindow = self.create_table_log()
        self.tableLogWindow.show()

        self.vbox.pack_start(self.tableTreeWindow)
        self.add(self.vbox)
        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()

    def create_table_tree(self):
        return clTableTree()

    def create_table_log(self):
        return clTableLog()

    def open_tree_widget(self, arg0, arg1):
        self.replace_widget(self.tableLogWindow, self.tableTreeWindow)


    def open_log_widget(self,  arg0, arg1):
        self.replace_widget(self.tableTreeWindow, self.tableLogWindow)

    def replace_widget(self, current, new):

        container = current.parent
        assert container # is "current" inside a container widget?

        props = {}
        for pspec in gtk.container_class_list_child_properties(container):
            props[pspec.name] = container.child_get_property(current, pspec.name)

        gtk.Container.remove(container, current)
        container.add(new)

        for name, value in props.items():
            container.child_set_property(new, name, value)    

PyApp()
gtk.main()
```